Discord bot / role
I am writing a bot for my discord server (via disnake), sometimes I have to restart it through the developer panel (discord.dev).
When I added him to the server, I changed his native role (which is called the same as the bot itself) to another one, but when the bot restarts, it flies back to the "native" one. Is it possible to use the code in the bot to immediately set the name of its native role?
I tried to find information on the Internet, but I didn't find anything, not even a similar one. Just how to change his status (watching/playing).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

IMPORTANT POINTS TO NOTE HERE:

guild.get_guild(GUILD_ID): Replace GUILD_ID with your server's ID.
guild.get_member(bot.user.id).top_role: Retrieves the bot's highest
role in the server, which should be the "native" role unless
overridden by a higher custom role.
bot_role.edit(name=desired_role_name): Changes the role name to the
desired one.

